Organizing an Azure ML project with multiple step scripts and shared modules
Starting Point
I am setting up a codebase for an Azure ML with Python project. The project has a main.py script that builds the pipeline and triggers its execution on Azure. The pipeline consists of several steps, each step in a separate script (step1.py, step2.py, etc.). Both the step scripts and the main script use functions specified in separate modules.
I wish to organize the project with the following folder structure:
project
|   main.py
|   
+---modules
|       __init__.py
|       module1.py
|       module2.py
|       
\---step_scripts
        step1.py
        step2.py

Issue
From the step scripts, I cannot access the modules using relative imports. This seems to be because Azure executes each step as a main script with __name__ = "__main__".

Considered Solutions
1. Change the Project Structure
I can avoid relative imports if the step scripts do not live in a "parallel folder" to the modules. For example:
project
|   main.py
|   step1.py
|   step2.py
|   
\---modules
        __init__.py
        module1.py
        module2.py

While this would work, I am not happy with having the main script and step scripts in the same folder. A different version seems unnecessarily nested:
project
|   main.py
|   
\---step_scripts
    |   step1.py
    |   step2.py
    |   
    \---modules
            __init__.py
            module1.py
            module2.py

2. Modify the Search Path
Appending folders to the search path using sys.path is a common workaround. However, based on past experience, this solution works but is a bit fragile. Given that my scripts are meant to run on Azure, I am also  concerned about potential side effects on the compute cluster.
Question
What are the best practices for organizing an Azure ML project with multiple step scripts and shared modules? Are there any robust solutions to handle relative imports in this context, or is there a better way to structure the project to avoid these issues?

Is my approach working better for you?

There are many ways you can solve this.
First, while passing the source folder to the job.
In your step scripts while you submit the job to cluster you need to pass the source directory, there you pass the folder consists of all the dependencies and modules. Relative to this source directory you access these modules.
And you can access this like "./modules" in your step script.
For the above case your folder structure will like below.
project
|   main.py
|   
\---step_scripts
    |   step1.py
    |   step2.py
    | 
    \---src_dir
        |  #any other dependencies
        \---modules
            __init__.py
            module1.py
            module2.py

This is not much nested like you think, this is also a better structure.
Next, you don't want nesting like above keep your modules folder separately and set the root folder in environment variable.
To avoid appending folders path to sys.path you can use find_packages() to install your modules.
Refer this stack solution for more information
